# One or more constraints have not been satisfied. Cannot install project facet Java 1.8. Some version of this project facet is already installed

Tags: eclipse, macos, glassfish, facet

I am creating a new "Dynamic Web Project" on Eclipse. I use MacOS Mojave.
 And I am using Glassfish as a server. In the last step of creation I get following error
-
[image: Error]

 After this step, a Dynamic Web Project is created, but doesnt do things like-

1. Not showing Java EE Tools(so as to add/create deployment descriptor)
2. Not exporting to war file. It instead shows me following, where I cant select my project
   .
   [image: error while exporting]

**Someone please help !!**

**EDIT: I have worked earlier on Tomcat, and never had this issue**

Comment: Does it also happen with other servers?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421913/cannot-install-project-facet-error-while-creating-a-project

Comment: No @nitind. I have been using Tomcat. Never had this issue. And I am using Glassfish for the first time.

Comment: OK, would make sense to mention what you already tried to save you and the users some time.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Java 1.8 SE installed.
Please, check the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine` folder:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
ls -la
```

Remove the versions using the following command

```
sudo rm -rf "...different version than 1.8..."
```

If you don't have the `jdk1.8.0_XXX.jdk` (XXX can be any number) folder in the previous folder, you must install it using the following link:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html