# Cannot create Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse, project facet already installed

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

So I am new to working with web and server related projects and I am trying to create a new Dynamic Web Project on the Eclipse IDE.

After clicking finish on the "new dynamic web project" window, a new project is created (though it is missing most folders) and the window remains open. If I hit Finish again, I am prompted with this error: "Cannot install project facet Java 10. Some version of this project is already installed."

If I simply close the window, after the project is created, it lacks files I am seeing in examples online, and I cannot create a new servlet for it.

The following query: ["Cannot install project facet" error while creating a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421913/cannot-install-project-facet-error-while-creating-a-project)
Is not really helpful as it relates to creating a project from existing code and that seemed to be the source of the issue.

I already tried using different project names, and web module version but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which options are you picking from the wizard? Is this on the latest release?

Comment: @nitind Default project location, target runtime: none; web module version: 3.0; default configuration, Generate Web.xml
Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
Build id: 20210910-1417

Comment: If there's more information in the Error Log, great, otherwise you're on a release that's over a year old and the only thing to do is get up to date and see if it keeps happening (and if it then has error log content).

Comment: try **Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers** (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers) , not **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the problem was indeed with the version.

Updating to the latest version of Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers fixed the issue.

Comment: As this is a simple answer it could have been placed in the comments and the question closed.